# Обновление токена из react-приложения при серфинге между страницами

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jwt

Есть web-приложение, написанное на React. При нажатии кнопки "Авторизоваться" происходит авторизация на внешнем OAuth-сервисе. На бэкенде формируется собственный jwt-токен с ограниченным ttl (час) и отдается приложению, где сохраняется в локальном хранилище. Refresh-token сохраняется на бэкенде в БД. Приложение отслеживает expiration time и спустя час выдает сообщение об окончании сессии.

Хотелось бы, чтобы при активном использовании приложения, сессия обновлялась в фоне, а сообщение об истечении выдавалось при явном бездействии. При отправке данных на бэкенд нет никаких проблем. В заголовки запроса добавляется токен и, в случае обновления, новый токен возвращается вместе с ответом.

Но обычный серфинг между страницами осуществляется средствами react-router и фактически не происходит обращений к бэкенду, чтобы отослать токен в заголовках.

Как поступить?

- Запрашивать состояние при каждом переходе между компонентами?
- Запрашивать состояние при приближении окончания сессии?
- Запрашивать состояние через определенные промежутки времени?
- Или какой-то другой способ?

Comment: На чем бекенд? На сколько критична кроссбраузерная поддержка?

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach бэкенд на php+symfony, кроссбраузерность ие11+

Comment: Я только не пойму в чем реально проблема? У Вас большинство роутов публичные? Если да, то по какой именно причине вы не хотите позвоить ходить по ним пользователю с недействительным токеном? Ну а если троуты приватные, то о чем вы вообще переживаете, ведь токен будет при каждом переходе сверятся (вы же реализовали приватные роуты?). Хотя может у Вас что-то ещё?

Comment: @OlmerDale может и так. Пока оставлено как есть. Прод покажет, может я действительно придумываю трудности)

Comment: Если стоит задача в том чтобы обнулять сессию в зависимости от времени (например в банковской системе), и прям это строгое правило то нужно искать решение. Но в целом я согласен с @OlmerDale, пока нет никаких запросов на бекенд, пусть себе ходит по вьюхам, нового же он ничего не увидит.

Answer (score 0):

С учетом Вашего стека и требований я бы посоветовал использовать [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API):

- независит от основного сайта
- поддерживается в [современных браузерах](https://caniuse.com/#search=web%20worker)

Они создают отдельный тред процессов, и не будут влиять на сайт, поэтому можно реализовать таймер для периодичных запросов без переживаний за перфоманс.